# Como criar Models no Laravel a partir de tabelas já criadas no banco de dados Mysql

Tags: laravel

Bom dia galera, estou com uma dúvida no Laravel, eu tinha uma base de dados criada no Mysql e utilizer o Xethron/migrations-generator para criar as migrations a partir das tabelas criadas no banco, mas como posso gerar as Models no Laravel a partir das migrations que estão criadas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daywison, não sei se entendi.

Você gostaria de criar os models a partir de um comando que gere os models automaticamente ou a dúvida é como criar os models com os nomes das tabelas já existentes.

Se for a primeira opção segue um pacote que você pode utilizar https://github.com/reliese/laravel
. Se for a segunda seguinte opção segue o trecho do código:

```
 
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductPeople extends Model
{
    // Nome da tabela existente
    protected $table = 'fornecedores';

}
```

Acredito que seja a primeira, mas coloquei as duas opções caso alguém precise. ;)

Espero ter ajudado!